# Can I solve this integral with a squared sum in it?

Tags: integration, symbolic-computation

[image]

Title says it all. By now I have tried by hand and I think that it is indeed solvable, but I can't handle the very long terms.

I tried to run the thing through SAGEs integrator:

```
%var x, y, z, i, n
ai = function('ai')
xi = function('xi')
yi = function('yi')
zi = function('zi')

gauss(a,x,y,z) = a * e^(-(x^2+y^2+z^2)/2)
f(x,y,z) = (sum(  gauss(ai(i),x-xi(i), y-yi(i), z-zi(i))  ,i,1,n))^2

integral(integral(integral(f,x),y),z)
```

Which results in:

```
(x, y, z) |--> integrate(integrate(integrate(sum(ai(i)*e^(-1/2*x^2 - 1/2*y^2 - 1/2*z^2 + x*xi(i) - 1/2*xi(i)^2 + y*yi(i) - 1/2*yi(i)^2 + z*zi(i) - 1/2*zi(i)^2), i, 1, n)^2, x), y), z)
```

So I think it is telling me that it is not possible?

Funny thing is that if I remove the outer `^2` it has no problem with coming up with a result. Problem is that I need that to calculate the absolute area under the integral. Is there a better way to achieve this?

**edit just to avoid confusion:** I asked the same question on StackOverflow but it seemed to be a bad fit there.

Comment: Yes, it's possible... it's a sum of exponentials of negative definite quadratics.  Each term is a Gaussian integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compared to the numeric solution this is the correct solution:

$\iiint\limits_{\rm I\!R^3} \left( \sum_{i=0}^n  a_i e^{-\frac{(x-b_i)^2+(y-c_i)^2+(z-d_i)^2}{2}} \right)^2 = \frac{1}{8}\pi^{\frac{3}{2}} \sum_{i=0}^n \left( a_i^2 erf(x-b_i) erf(y-c_i) erf(z-d_i) \right) + \\ \frac{1}{4}\pi^\frac{3}{2} \sum_{i=0}^n \sum_{j=i}^n \left( a_i a_j erf(x - \frac{b_i+b_j}{2}) erf(y-\frac{c_i+c_j}{2}) erf(z-\frac{d_i+d_j}{2})  e^{ \left( - \frac{1}{4}(b_i-b_j)^2 - \frac{1}{4}(c_i-c_j)^2 - \frac{1}{4}(d_i-d_j)^2  \right) }   \right) $

Jacks answer is not giving me the results I expect, but put me on the right track to solve this myself.

Comment: $\iiint_{\mathbb{R}^3}$ means the improper integral over the whole $\mathbb{R}^3$, hence the answer cannot depend on $x,y$ or $z$. Probably we just understood two different things since the notation $\int_x$ is not very common: you considered the indefinite integral, I considered the improper integral.

Comment: Sooo ... the correct notation would be without the R^3 below the integral signs? Sorry for the confusion then, (as probably many people) I don't deal with this often. But it really helped me in this case. Sad thing that it's O(n^2) ;)

Comment: the correct notation depends on what the OP wants (still unclear). If he wants the numerical value of the integral over the whole $\mathbb{R}^3$, my answer gives it; if he wants the symbolic antiderivative of the given function, your answer is clearly the right one.

Comment: The OP's me, that's why I am trying to sort this out. I need the "numerical value of the integral" in a given area. But I did that with the equation above    and putting that into the "F(b)-F(a)" for 3 dimensions. I also tried your equation but it gives me a different result. Not to claim that it's "wrong", but it doesn't give the results I am expecting.

Comment: I understand the situation, I computed the integral over the whole $\mathbb{R}^3$. If you compute the integral over a smaller region, you get a smaller number :D

Answer (score 4):

That is perfectly doable by hand. Just expand the square and exploit:

$$ \iiint_\mathbb{R^3} \exp\left(-\frac{(x-a_i)^2+(y-b_i)^2+(z-c_i)^2}{2}\right)\,d\mu = (2\pi)^{3/2},$$

$$ \iiint_\mathbb{R^3} \exp\left(-\frac{(x-a_i)^2+(x-a_j)^2+(y-b_i)^2+(y-b_j)^2+(z-c_i)^2+(z-c_j)^2}{2}\right)\,d\mu = \pi^{3/2}\exp\left(-\frac{(a_i-a_j)^2+(b_i-b_j)^2+(c_i-c_j)^2}{4}\right).$$
By setting $g(A,B,C)=\exp\left(-\frac{A^2+B^2+C^2}{4}\right)$ it follows that:

$$\iiint_{\mathbb{R}^3}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i\cdot e^{-\frac{(x-b_i)^2+(x-c_i)^2+(x-d_i)^2}{2}}\right)^2\,d\mu =\\= (2\pi)^{3/2}\cdot\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^2+2(\pi)^{3/2}\cdot\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}a_i a_j\cdot g(b_i-b_j,c_i-c_j,d_i-d_j).$$

Comment: Hmm ... I don't understand that. Where is the sum gone? And where do the `_j` indices come from?

Comment: Seeing your reputation on this site you probably know what you are doing. But I fail to see the connection between my question and your answer, do you care to elaborate?

Comment: @fho: you integrand function is the square of a sum of Gaussian functions. I am just saying: expand the square and use the above identities to integrate it termwise.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me to find the solution. I also tried your solution, but apparently I still didn't get it. I put my solution in the question. For the sake of learning: I probably haven't communicated my problem formally correct. If that is the case I'd be glad if someone could point it out to me.

Comment: I've gone over this one more time. Your solution is correct, if you remove the initial $2$. That term doesn't apply to the first sum.

Comment: And ... by now I have understood what you meant by expand the square ... stupid me.